# <ion-slide> not working when I add two <ion-slides> in my app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I am creating an application with tabs. In ** tab2.page.html ** I have 2  inside , I leave my code to understand better:

```
<ion-slides class="slidesTab2" #slidesTab2 pager="false">
    <ion-slide>
      ---- código ----
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      ---- código ----
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

--- código ---

<ion-col>
   <ion-button shape="round" size="small" fill="outline" color="tertiary" (click)="goToNext()">
   Next
   </ion-button>
</ion-col>
   <ion-button shape="round" size="small" fill="outline" color="tertiary" (click)="goToPrev()">
   Prev
   </ion-button>
</ion-col>
```

and its corresponding class ** tab2.page.ts **:

```
@ViewChild('slidesTab2', { static: true }) slidesTab2: IonSlides;
 --- código ---

goToNext() {
   this.slidesTab2.lockSwipes( false );
   this.slidesTab2.slideNext();
   this.slidesTab2.lockSwipes( true );
}

goToPrev() {
   this.slidesTab2.lockSwipes( false );
   this.slidesTab2.slidePrev();
   this.slidesTab2.lockSwipes( true );
}
```

In ** tab3.page.html ** I have 2 other  inside of , I leave the code to understand better:

```
<ion-slides class="slidesTab3" #slidesTab3 pager="false">
    <ion-slide>
      ---- código ----
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      ---- código ----
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

--- código ---

<ion-col>
   <ion-button shape="round" size="small" fill="outline" color="tertiary" (click)="goToNext()">
   Next
   </ion-button>
</ion-col>
   <ion-button shape="round" size="small" fill="outline" color="tertiary" (click)="goToPrev()">
   Prev
   </ion-button>
</ion-col>
```

and its corresponding class ** tab3.page.ts **:

```
@ViewChild('slidesTab3', { static: true }) slidesTab3: IonSlides;
 --- código ---

goToNext() {
   this.slidesTab3.lockSwipes( false );
   this.slidesTab3.slideNext();
   this.slidesTab3.lockSwipes( true );
}

goToPrev() {
   this.slidesTab3.lockSwipes( false );
   this.slidesTab3.slidePrev();
   this.slidesTab3.lockSwipes( true );
}
```

The problem that only works the first slides I open. That is, I open the application, I open tab2 and the slides works perfectly. And if I next open tab3, the slides declared in this class doesn't work. I've tried printing the active index with ** slide.getActiveIndex (); ** on each function, but the slides I open second, the one that doesn't work, prints empty. How can I fix it to make 2 slides work? Thank you.

Comment: You are missing an end quote in each of your buttons where you define color as tertiary.

Comment: Yes, thanks. There was an error copying the code. The error still remains.